# Setting a field on a form - xPages

Tags: xpages

I am a newbie to xPages, not to Notes though.  I have a type ahead field that works and it brings in the value needed.  After that, I want to lookup information for the key they just entered and fill in fields on the form for that document.  In the onChange event, I have the following code.  I get the record but the setValue isn't working or at least it's not displaying on the xPage.  Can someone help?

```
var path = database.getFilePath().split(database.getFileName())[0];
var lookupDB:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(database.getServer(), "db2.nsf");
 var vLookup:NotesView = lookupDB.getView("viewname");
var compID = getComponent("typeaheadfield").getValue()
var custDoc:NotesDocument = vLookup.getDocumentByKey(compID);
document1.setValue("fieldname", custDoc.getItemValue("custdocfieldname"));
```

Comment: I think you just miss the partial refresh of your form after the code is executed. Check the refresh/submit options of your onchange event.

Comment: Thank you.  I had partial update but the wrong field and only one field to update.  I made it Full and it works (I have more than one field to update).  Thanks.

Comment: I will add this as an answer that you could accept

Comment: Mike, even though you got it to work with a full update, note that Oliver in his answer is recommending (as am I) that you perform a partial refresh on the panel/DIV/Table that you want updated. Full refreshes create a flashing screen experience which is a poor UX. (Also don't forget to push the big green checkmark to accept his answer)

Comment: By the way: in the last line I'd check if you really found a document to prevent runtime exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you do a partial refresh of your field or form. For the form you can define an ID for a sorrounding DIV and choose that ID as partial refresh ID in your onChange event.

Comment: If your XPage has validation, you'll also need to use "Process data without validations". Otherwise validation will trigger and the partial refresh will skip the phase where your SSJS runs. Bear in mind that you'll still get an error if e.g. a text value is entered into a number field. That's because to store the value in the dominoDocument datasource, it needs to convert to the relevant Java data type, which would throw an error if trying to put text in a Double. Best practice recommendation is always to include an errors control in the area you're refreshing, so you know if it hits an error